# Kivy widgets have almost-unreadable text

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am having issues with my installation of Kivy on my Windows 10 machine. I've copied the "Hello, World" example from [the Kivy website](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/basic.html), but when I run it, almost nothing shows up. The screen is black except for an extremely faint "Hello world". On a different computer (also a Windows 10 machine), I tried running the exact same code, and the "Hello world" message was white and fully readable.

Here is the code that I am running:

```py
import kivy
kivy.require("1.10.1")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Here is a screencap of what's actually being displayed on my machine:

[image: simple label testing]

If you look very closely, you can barely see the "Hello world" message in the middle of the image.

I have Kivy version 1.10.1, using Glew, running on Python 3.6. I have Cython and Pygame installed and updated to the latest version, though I installed them after I had initially installed Kivy and they didn't seem to fix the issue. I have tried to do a reinstall of Kivy and it did not seem to change anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT -

I have done a complete reinstall of all my Python packages downloaded with pip and it seems to be working a lot better. However, there is still a difference between what I'm seeing on my computer versus what I'm seeing on the other computer.

Here is what I'm seeing on my computer:

[image: testing on my computer]

The text is still not white like it is supposed to be, instead it's a gray color.

Here is what I'm seeing on the other computer:

[image: testing with a different coputer]

EDIT -

An update - If I put my `Label` into a `FloatLayout` or a `StackLayout`, it shows up like it's supposed to. Here's code that works, as opposed to what I pasted above:

```py
import kivy
kivy.require("1.10.1")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        layout = FloatLayout() # this can be swapped with StackLayout()
        layout.add_widget(Label(text="Hello, world"))
        return layout


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

EDIT -

Expanding on what's above, it seems that if, for a widget that is nested n times into layouts, if n is an even number, that widget's text will be dimmed. Here's the code I used to test this.

```py
import kivy
kivy.require("1.10.1")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        layouts = []
        nest = 6 # with nest equal to 6, the Label's text is dimmed.
        # if nest were equal to 5, the Label's text would not be dimmed.
        for _ in range(nest):
            innerLayout = StackLayout()
            if len(layouts) != 0:
                layouts[-1].add_widget(innerLayout)
            layouts.append(innerLayout)

        layouts[-1].add_widget(Label(text="Hello, world"))
        return layouts[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

EDIT -

I have found another condition under which Kivy's text is inexplicably dimmed. When the text has newlines (or wraps around to the next line), the text after the first line will be muted.

Here's a code snippet.

```py
import kivy
kivy.require("1.10.1")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout

longStr = """
I am making this text very long with newlines so that I can prove
that the Kivy label's text is faint when it goes to the next
line. It's very finnicky and I don't know what would be causing
this issue, though it probably isn't that big of one because no
one else seems to be having it.
"""


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        layout = StackLayout()
        layout.add_widget(Label(text=longStr))
        return layout


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Here's what it looks like on the affected machine.

[image: long string test image]

I have also realized that some of the images, when viewed as a part of this post, don't seem to have any text at all, when on Imgur they are easier to see (still, not by much). I am accounting this to StackOverflow's light theme.

Comment: Working fine for me. Since you don't import the other modules there's a tiny tiny chance they are the culprit.

Comment: @Iapras: Have you installed `angle`?

Comment: @ikolim I reinstalled Kivy using angle, but now I'm unable to start the program at all. I am going to continue using glew.

Comment: Is there a `my.kv` file nearby? If you change the `Label` to `Label(text='Hello world', color=(1, 1, 1, 1))`, does it improve?

Comment: @JohnAnderson Changing the text color of the label seems to change nothing. The code I put in the question is the only code being run.

Comment: So, there is not a file named `my.kv` in the same folder as your python code? If there is no `my.kv` file and changing the `color` has no effect, then I am stumped.

Comment: Try changing `MyApp` to something odd, like `BubbasApp`. See if that changes anything.

Comment: @JohnAnderson There are no `.kv` files in the directory where my code is (or, for that matter, on the computer at all). I've tried changing the app name to something else, but nothing changed. I'm very confused as well. It should work, and I'm running the exact same code on other machines and it *is* working, but I don't know what about the different environments could be causing such a difference in the display. Thank you very much for trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug introduced in a recent SDL2 version, you can work around it for now by running `python -m pip install kivy.deps.sdl2==0.1.18` to install a slightly older version, or wait for a new Kivy release (coming soon) where it is also fixed.